# Have embedded images open with FancyBox, not in new window

Tags: image, fancybox, embed

This section of code in my /js/global.js file activate each image to open in a new window when clicked.  Is it possible to alter this code to have each open in a FancyBox instead?  I have downloaded a FancyBox plugin for a Vanilla forum I am running, and it currently only targets images embedded in posts After You Click On The Post Itself.  On the main page, clicking on an image opens a new window.

```
// Shrink large images to fit into message space, and pop into new window when clicked.
// This needs to happen in onload because otherwise the image sizes are not yet known.
    jQuery(window).load(function() {
       var props = ['Width', 'Height'], prop;
       while (prop = props.pop()) {
          (function (natural, prop) {
             jQuery.fn[natural] = (natural in new Image()) ? 
             function () {
                return this[0][natural];
             } : 
             function () {
                var 
                   node = this[0],
                   img,
                   value;
                if (node.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'img') {
                   img = new Image();
                   img.src = node.src,
                   value = img[prop];
                }
                return value;
             };
          }('natural' + prop, prop.toLowerCase()));
       }
       jQuery('div.Message img').each(function(i,img) {
          var img = jQuery(img);
          var container = img.closest('div.Message');
          if (img.naturalWidth() > container.width() && container.width() > 0) {
             img.wrap('<a href="'+$(img).attr('src')+'"></a>');
          }
       });
       // Let the world know we're done here
       jQuery(window).trigger('ImagesResized');
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an specific *class* to your wrapped images, modifying this line

```
img.wrap('<a href="'+$(img).attr('src')+'"></a>');
```

... into this :

```
img.wrap('<a class="fancybox" href="'+$(img).attr('src')+'"></a>');
```

Then bind fancybox to that selector ("`.fancybox`") in a custom script like :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox();
```

This assumes that you have properly loaded the fancybox js and css files.